# Использовать введенные ссылки в другом классе

Tags: java, android

Сори за может глупый вопрос, но всё же

Как сохранить и (главное потом использовать) ссылки, которые пользователь вводит в диалог(потом вставляет в список)?

```
String string = input.getText().toString();
```

код диалога:

```
private void showAddVideoDialog(final int pos) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout_add_video, (ViewGroup) getView(), false);
    final EditText input = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.edt_videoUrl);
    builder.setView(viewInflated);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            String string = input.getText().toString();
            getIdUrl(string, pos);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Отмена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

код адаптера

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    List<ImageUpload> imageUploads;
    int resource;



    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<ImageUpload> imageUploads, int resource) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUploads = imageUploads;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final GridHolder viewHolder;
    //   ImageUpload currentImageUpload = imageUploads.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new GridHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            if (imageUploads.get(position).getOutputMetadata().getFilename().equals("null")) {
                convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.item_upload_default, parent, false);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.item_upload, parent, false);
            }
            viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_upload);
            viewHolder.closeView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo_close_btn);
            viewHolder.progress = (ProgressWheel) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loader_photo);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (GridHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (imageUploads.get(position).getOutputMetadata().getFilename().equals("null")) {
            viewHolder.photo.setImageResource(resource);
        } else {
            ImageUpload mobile = imageUploads.get(position);
            if (imageUploads.get(position).isLoadImage())
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile.getOutputMetadata().getVideoUrl()))
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_RESIZE + 150 + "x" + 150 + "/" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + mobile.getOutputMetadata().getFilename())
                            .into(viewHolder.photo, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    viewHolder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {

                                }
                            });
                else {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(mobile.getOutputMetadata().getVideoUrl()).into(viewHolder.photo);
                    viewHolder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            else {
                File f = new File(imageUploads.get(position).getPath());
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(f)
                        .into(viewHolder.photo);
            }

            viewHolder.closeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((GridView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
  );
            }
            return convertView;
        }
```

надо использовать в `viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener`

Comment: другой класс это другая активити, другой фрагмент или обычный класс?

Comment: @pavlofff диалог куда пользователь вводит ссылку находится во фрагменте.
использовать хочу в адаптере.

Comment: @Inkognito так приведите код адаптера, и диалога.

Comment: @Asgard  обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос, вам стоить посмотреть [данную статью про хранение данных](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html).

> В Android есть несколько способов хранения данных:
>
> Preferences - в качестве аналогии можно привести виндовые INI-файлы
>
> SQLite - база данных, таблицы
>
> обычные файлы - внутренние и внешние (на SD карте)

Далее, смотря по тому, какое значение играют введённые пользователем данные, выбрать один из данных вариантов. Если ссылок у вас может быть много у каждого пользователя, скорее всего вам лучше всего сохранять эти данные в базе данных, в [SQLite](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html).

Comment: не совсем, у меня просто пользователь во фрагменте >вводит в диалоге ссылки, которые заносятся в список gridView. вон то что он вставлял мне надо сохранить где то и после использовать в адаптере.